# Difficulties in interpreting this question

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, parsing

> Have you ever been employed by or done any type of work, such as consulting or contract work for any financial services institution in Australia or elsewhere such as a bank, building society or insurance company?

Is this question asking whether I have any work experience in any financial services institution? (not work experience in general?)

Comment: See [*such as*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/such-as)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence at issue can be written as two separate sentences:

> Have you ever been employed by any financial services institution in Australia or elsewhere such as a bank, building society or insurance company? Have you ever done any type of work, such as consulting or contract work for any financial services institution in Australia or elsewhere such as a bank, building society or insurance company?

This question is asking whether you have any experience in the field of financial services. Have you worked (been employed) at any financial institutions? If so, where? In Australia or another country? Or have you done any finance-related work for financial institutions?

This question asks about your work experience in finance. Any experience with banks, insurance companies, or building societies counts. If you have such experience, you should also specify where the companies you have worked for are located.

Answer (score 0):

What is says would be so odd that I would assume that a comma has been missed. I can't imagine that it would ask "have you ever done any type of work" and then give a long and complex example of what "work" means in the financial services.

It would be odd because 1) I know what "work" is, and 2) Only giving examples from finance doesn't give a good example of "work".

So there must be a "missing" comma. I suggest it should be written :

> Have you ever been employed by or done any type of work, such as consulting or contract work`,` for any financial services institution in Australia or elsewhere, such as a bank, building society or insurance company?

The section "such as consulting or contract work" is a parenthesis. Removing the examples gives the basic question:

> Have you ever been employed by or done any type of work for any financial services institution in Australia or elsewhere.

So it is only asking about experience in the financial services sector.

Comment: you nailed it. This sentence has a fragment